# Docker Codeigniter3 cannot connect with SQL server database

Tags: sql-server, docker, codeigniter

I am new to docker and I am trying to deploy docker container on my local machine. However, Codeigniter3 cannot connect with the SQL server database.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:7.4.23-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY src/ .
USER root
RUN chmod 777 ./system
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

RUN a2enmod rewrite

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nano wget curl gnupg2

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - 
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list 
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev 
RUN pecl install sqlsrv
RUN pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
RUN docker-php-ext-enable sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv

RUN echo "extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`/30-pdo_sqlsrv.ini 

RUN echo "extension=sqlsrv.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files" | 
sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`/30-sqlsrv.ini

RUN service apache2 restart
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: ci-mssql-db-app
    image: ci-mssql-db-app:1.0.0
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
  db:
    container_name: mssql
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU12-ubuntu-20.04
    restart: always
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      SA_PASSWORD: "Testing123"
      MSSQL_PID: "Developer"
```

Codeigniter3 **database.php** file configuration:

```
$db['default'] = array(
     'dsn'  => '',
     'hostname' => 'db:1433',
     'username' => 'admin',
     'password' => 'admin',
     'database' => 'ciapp',
     'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
     'dbprefix' => '',
     'pconnect' => FALSE,
     'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
     'cache_on' => FALSE,
     'cachedir' => '',
     'char_set' => 'utf8',
     'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
     'swap_pre' => '',
     'encrypt' => FALSE,
     'compress' => FALSE,
     'stricton' => FALSE,
     'failover' => array(),
     'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Here, I have set hostname = 'db:1433' as it points to the service name so that it will get the ip address of db service automatically. And, SQL server runs on 1433 port by default.

After running the docker command

```
docker-compose up --build
```

I am getting this error,

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
```

[Error Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1kmm.png)

I am struggling to solve it for almost two weeks. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Do you have a startup script somewhere that creates an SQL Login for `admin` with password `admin`, and a new database `ciapp`?

Comment: No. After creating the SQL server container, I am planning to enter the db container using bash to create the DB and tables.

Comment: are your `app-container` and `db-container` on same network?

Comment: shev anto yes. Both of my containers are on the same network.

Comment: if both containers are on the same network , try localhost instead of db in your connection  i.e db:1433 -> localhost:1433